# How to make a search box that searches for attributes' value then hide or show elements based on users input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty new to Javascript. I'm trying to make a search box that searches for images based users input. Here's what I got so far.

```
<input type="text" id="search-box">

<a class="image-link" href="photos/02.jpg" data-rel="lightcase:collection" data-lc-caption="The lake was so calm today. We had a great view of the snow on the mountains from here." data-alt="Lake">
  <img class="image-link" src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Lake">
</a>
```

So, I'm trying to make a search that uses attributes value to display/hide the images. For example, if I typed "lake" in the search box this image and any images that have the word "lake" as their attributes' value would appear and hid the rest.

Here's my Javascript code so far. I'm not quite sure if I'm on the right path here. I'd appreciate any help, please.

```
let y = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

document.getElementById("search-box").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  x = document.getElementById("search-box");
  x = x.value.toLowerCase();
  console.log(x);

  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i += 1) {
    e = descent[i].getAttribute("data-lc-caption").toLowerCase();
    console.log(e);
  }

  if (e.includes(x)) {
    console.log(yes);
  }
});
```

I used console.logs to check my results. I know that I'll have to remove them eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on right path. Here are few general suggestions based on your code

1 Use better variable names, for example instead `y` name it something
    like `videoLinks`

2 Use `const` unless you know you will need to change value of variable at some point

3 Do not declare variable by just saying `x = 'something'`. That way you are creating global variables and using memory for no reason

4 Use `onchange` input because onkeyup will fire only on typing, what is user pastes in content?

Now the code:

```
document.getElementById('search-box').addEventListener('change', function() {
  const linksWithImages = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
  const searchValue = document.getElementById("search-box").value
  for (let i = 0; i < linksWithImages.length) {
    if (linksWithImages[i].getAttribute('data-lc-caption') === searchValue) {
      linksWithImages[i].style.display === 'block'
    } else {
      linksWithImages[i].style.display === 'none'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestion! I got it to work. I did modify some codes a little though.  

       `if (linkedImages[i].getAttribute("data-lc-caption").toLowerCase().includes(inputValue))`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's improve the event listener by detecting change and call the main function only after the user finish typing. Then use RegExp instead of toLowerCase for Case-insensitive search. And finally, update the style.

Also, it's better to get the images by using class name instead of tag name.

```
const searchBox = document.getElementById("search-box");
const images = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

let globalTimeout = null;

// Detect for input change when user finish typing
searchBox.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    if (globalTimeout !== null)
        clearTimeout(globalTimeout);
    globalTimeout = setTimeout(onFinishTyping, 200);
});

function onFinishTyping() {
    const input = searchBox.value;
    globalTimeout = null;

    console.log("Searching for", input);
    for (let i = 0, length = images.length; i < length; i++) {
        const image = images[i];
        if (!image.getAttribute("data-lc-caption").match(new RegExp(input, "ig")))
            image.style.display = "none";
        else
            image.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('search-box').addEventListener('input', function() {
  const linksWithImages = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
  const searchValue = document.getElementById("search-box").value
  let i = 0, len = linksWithImages.length;
  for (; i < len; i++) {
      let lnk = linksWithImages[i];
      let val = lnk.getAttribute("data-lc-caption");
        lnk.style.visibility = val.indexOf(searchValue) > -1 ? "visible" : "hidden";
  }
})
```